# getReadableDatabase crashing, onCreate not being called

Tags: android, sql, database, oncreate, android-context

How is it in this code that the DatabaseHandler does not execute `onCreate()`?
This original list app runs great and I am in the beginning stages of trying to inject a database into the app so the list displays records instead of coded strings.

The Android Intellisense shows the availability of the methods but the application crashes when run. My suspicion is the `onCreate()` never gets called because the `Log.d` messages never show up in the logcat.
I have tried many combinations of the db instantiate or context passing to no avail.

I am pulling the logcat from the phone with adb logcat > lr.txt as I can not run an emulator because the development machine is AMD and not an Intel processor.

Here is the db method class:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// for our logs
public static final String TAG = "DatabaseHandler.java";

public TextView tvstatus;

// database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 8;

// database name
protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LoadRunner";

// table details
public String tableName = "loadrunner";
public String fieldObjectId = "id";
public String fieldObjectName = "name";
public String fieldObjectDescription = "description";

// constructor
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// creating table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "";
    this.tvstatus.setText("Creating table");

    sql += "CREATE TABLE " + tableName;
    sql += " ( ";
    sql += fieldObjectId + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ";
    sql += fieldObjectName + " TEXT, ";
    sql += fieldObjectDescription + " TEXT ";
    sql += " ) ";

    Log.d("Loadrunner", "Create table");
    db.execSQL(sql);
    this.tvstatus.setText("Table created...");

    // create the index for our INSERT OR REPLACE INTO statement.
    // this acts as the WHERE name="name input" AND description="description input"
    // if that WHERE clause is true, I mean, it finds the same name and description in the database,
    // it will be REPLACEd. 
    // ELSE, what's in the database will remain and the input will be INSERTed (new record)
    String INDEX = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX locations_index ON " 
                    + tableName + " (name, description)";
    
    db.execSQL(INDEX);
}

/*
 * When upgrading the database, it will drop the current table and recreate.
 */
```

Here is the Mainactivity method:
TableMainLayout is the next activity called that displays the list.
I received the original code from codeofaninja.com and am adding the database to it.
When I remark out the getreadabledatabase() the app runs fine with no database calls or records needed.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* Loads next module */

   db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
   db.getReadableDatabase();
    //this.db.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase this.db);
    Log.d("Loadrunner ", "Loadrunner MainActivity DB var");
    setContentView(new TableMainLayout(this));
    Log.d("Loadrunner ", "Loadrunner MainActivity Content set");
    //this.db.insertFast(40);
```

Here is the logcat:

> D/Database( 5891): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.example.tablefreezepane/databases/LoadRunner, flag = 6, file size = 3072
>
> D/Database( 5891): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.example.tablefreezepane/databases/LoadRunner, mode: delete, disk free size: 64 M, handle: 0x336f70
>
> W/ContentService(  121): binderDied() at ObserverNode name com.google.android.gsf.gservices
>
> D/Database( 5891): dbclose(): path = /data/data/com.example.tablefreezepane/databases/LoadRunner, handle = 0x336f70
>
> D/AndroidRuntime( 5891): Shutting down VM

And the app crash on the phone:

> The Application LoadRunner(process com.example.tablefreezepane) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Comment: In your log, did you see a error message of FATAL?

Comment: 1) Don't call `this.db.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase this.db);`, it is called automatically. 2) Also call `getWritableDatabase()` instead of `getReadableDatabase()`. 3) Change Database version to 9

Comment: >E/AndroidRuntime( 5891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

>E/AndroidRuntime( 5891): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tablefreezepane/com.example.tablefreezepane.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

>E/AndroidRuntime( 5891): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

>E/AndroidRuntime( 5891):  at com.example.tablefreezepane.DatabaseHandler.onCreate(DatabaseHandler.java:42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found issue!: this.tvstatus.setText("Table created..."); It was an activity problem all along. I dont think I have that form on the screen for display. I remmed it out and the app continued. So now I can pursue 2 issues. Clean up the display and start investigating the table created. Its on the phone. Thank you @Jemshit for the guidance. I'll take any more you care to offer. Oh, its a good day! –

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you get a reference of the textview. so tvstatus is pointing to nothing when you call.settext. this leads to nopointerexception..
  use findviewbyid to get a reference first.

Comment: Your idea can be more clear showing modified code with this comments.